# Handling rapid clicks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm building a site (with jQuery 1.4) which has a floating (fixed position) basket.

Current **working** functionality (**[Demo here](http://www.souliss.com/test/test.html)**):

- When the user clicks the basket itself it toggle slides open/closed and toggles a "locked on" class
- When the user clicks an 'add item' link in the page it slides open, adds an "on" class and fades in a notice saying that "item name" has been added

What I'm struggling with

- If the user clicked an 'add item' link: after 3 seconds the notice should fade out, the basket slide closed, and the "on" class be removed. **BUT** this needs to take into account if the user frantically clicks 10 things quickly; updating the added track name notice text without queueing up a bunch of fades/slides - rather just staying open nicely and then sliding closed 3 seconds from the last item being added. AND if the basket's class is "locked" (ie; opened by user already) then only the notice should fade out, the basket should remain open.

javascript so far

```
//Toggle basket directly
$("#basket-button").click(function(){
    $("#basket-contents").slideToggle();
    $("#floating-basket").toggleClass("locked on");
    return false
});
//Toggle basket with a 'buy now' button
$(".buy-button").click(function(){
    //open basket 
    $("#basket-contents").slideDown();
    $("#floating-basket").addClass("on");
    //set track name
    $("#basket-trackname").text($(this).attr('name'));
    //Display basket message
    $("#basket-message").fadeIn();
    return false
});
```

html

```
<a class="buy-button" name="Item Name one" href="#">Buy</a>
<a class="buy-button" name="Item Name two" href="#">Buy</a>

<div id="floating-basket">
    <div id="basket-message">
        <strong id="basket-trackname"></strong> added to basket!
    </div>
    <a href="/basket" id="basket-button">My Basket <span id="basket-number">0</span></a>
    <div id="basket-contents">
        lorem
        <a href="#">Checkout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/ajaxed-sliding-shopping-cart-with-jquery is the closest thing I found - but even this is problematic (if you add an item and quickly close the basket for example).

Would really appreciate some input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

learn about `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

```
var t = setTimeout(function(){ whattodo(); }, 3000);
```

will do anonym function, which basically consists only of `whattodo()` function (which could hide basket, etc.)

then in each click, `.stop()` animation and call:

```
clearTimeout(t); // clears previous timeout
t = setTimeout(function(){ whattodo(); }, 3000); //set new timeout
```

so, `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` are to time hiding in 3 seconds, while `.stop()` stops ongoing animation - learn more @ http://api.jquery.com/stop/ - basic usage:

```
$(myelementwithanimation).stop()
```

and more about timeouts: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: You don't have to create it as an anonym function, you can do <code>var t = setTimeout('whattodo()', 3000);</code>. This also lets you do paramatised calls: <code>var t = setTimeout('whattodo(\'string1\',false,29)', 3000);</code>

But either way is fine I've found :)

Comment: @Psytronic - I know about the expression version, but it doesn't work for me very good, while this way, it works. also, the syntax is coloured :D

Comment: Thanks, this was the nudge in the right direction I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for  .stop()

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea of what You need:

```
free=true;
function doSomeAnimation(){
//do what is done either way
if(free){
free=false;
$(something).addClass('foo').slideDown(function(){free=true;});
}
}
```

instead of cancelling the animations - just don't trigger them if they're already running

PS. Timeouts are ok, but You have to keep all of them handlers to be able to clear Timeout, so it gets ugly... ;)

Comment: why all of them? right now, he needs just one handler. And also, you can't time `if(free)` to start after 3 seconds.

Comment: Not all of them, but those You need to. This is just the idea of how it (IMHO) should be done in general. Like a design pattern. In the long run the setTimeout became something I try not to "overuse"